# Angular 2 router 3.0.0-rc.1 deactivate guard protecting group of routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I would like to create a deactivate guard that is trigerred only when navigating outside of child routes.

In rc4 (`"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1"`) this code was working as described:

```
path: '',
  component: RootComponent,
  canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],
  children: [{
    path: '',
    component: XComponent,
  }, {
    path: 'somepath',
    component: YComponent
  }]
}
```

In this example navigating from `XComponent` to `YComponent` did not trigger deactivate guard, but for example navigating to `"someNotChildComponent"` did.

After updating to `@angular/route 3.0.0-rc.1` guard is triggered for every path change. What is correct behavior? Are there better ways to handle this case?

Comment: If this problem can no longer be reproduced, it can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can add the

```
canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
```

inside your child routes definition instead of the parent route.

Comment: the thing is I would like to have a guard protecting from navigating outside of child routes not guard for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug, it works as expected now.